# Laravel Old Input 8.x

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

With Laravel 8.x it appears from the docs snippet below that using `old()` for the old input value is not necessary but I can't figure out how to not use it.

> Laravel allows you to keep input from one request during the next request. This feature is particularly useful for re-populating forms after detecting validation errors. However, if you are using Laravel's included validation features, it is unlikely you will need to manually use these methods, as some of Laravel's built-in validation facilities will call them automatically.

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/requests#old-input

I know I can do `<input name="field" value="{{ old('field') }}" />` but I'm unclear if that is the best / accepted way to include the original posted value during form validation errors.

I also tried this per another SO post:

```
    $validationRules = [
        'field' => 'required|max:255',
    ];

    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), $validationRules);

    if ($validator->fails()) {
        return redirect(route('item.create'))->withInput()->withErrors($validator);
    }
```

Can anyone shed some light on this?

Comment: The docs say to use the `old()` helper if you're using a blade template

Comment: not really sure what your question actually is

Comment: @AndyHolmes This is the part that made me think there was another way. "However, if you are using Laravel's included validation features, it is *unlikely you will need to manually use these methods*, as some of Laravel's built-in validation facilities will call them automatically."

Comment: @JSP it's probably worded more towards anyone using validation in an SPA setting, getting the responses back as JSON

Comment: @JSP any news/updates regarding this problem?

Comment: @Taguro I ended up using `old()`.  The copy read to me like it wasn't necessary but I couldn't figure out another way.  Not sure if that's helpful...

Answer (score 0):

```
$validationRules = [
    'field' => 'required|max:255',
];

$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), $validationRules);

if ($validator->fails()) {
    //Add the $request->flash() to include the errors
    $request->flash(); 
    return redirect(route('item.create'))->withErrors($validator);
}
```